# responseObject on the new AF request

Tags: swift, promise, alamofire

I have a function that worked fine with the old Alamofire request, however, after I updated the pods with the new 5.4.1 version the code doesn't work anymore. I'm just wondering how to convert the `respondObject` to work with the new "AF.request? I'm guessing I now need to use `responseJASON`?!

```
  import Alamofire
  import Promises

  func tab_HomeEv() -> Promise<[Shr_flw]>{
    //yesterdayDate
    //  lambdaCall()
    
    let eventParams: NSDictionary = ["userID" : "ap-southeast-2:b4....","flwsG": "235"]
    
    
    return Promise <[Shr_flw]>{
        fullfil, reject -> Void in
        
        
        return (  Alamofire.request("https://jxvvue....com/dev/tab..", method: .post, parameters: eventParams as? [String:AnyObject] , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self.headerToken() ).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<eventFollowShrd_Resp>)
            in
            switch(response.result){
            case .success:
                
                let eventHomeCRespons = response.result.value
                fullfil((eventHomeCRespons?.evFlows ?? []))
                
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                reject(error)
            }
            }
            
            
        )
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Currently, I'm getting the following error on the Promise: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`
Also on `DataResponse` : `Generic type 'DataResponse' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)`

I tried using `.responseJSON` instead of `.responseObject` but I don't know how to format the code so I can have  `DataResponse<eventFollowShrd_Resp>`  and not get any errors.

Comment: Unrelated but `eventParams` in Swift is neither `NSDictionary` nor `[String:AnyObject]`

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicated, `DataResponse` is now doubly generic, with both the response type and error type part of the generic signature. You can use the `AFDataResponse<T>` alias to provide the error type for you (`AFError` by default).

Additionally, `responseObject` is not part of Alamofire, it sounds like something you wrote or that's part of an external library. I suggest you use `responseDecodable` with `Decodable` types to replace that functionality.

Finally, if your deployment target is iOS 13 or higher, you can use Alamofire's Combine integration rather than custom promises.